# Jquery [object Object] instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and it works almost fine. The problem is that instead of displaying the text message inside the div, it print the following message: [object Object].. I browsed the web and following threads, using the function:

console.log() I can see the message in the console (thanks to firebug), but I cannot see it in the div...

what am I missing??

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_mail").validate({
        rules: {
            'email': {
                required: true,
            },
            'oggetto': {
                required: true,
            },
            'msg': {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mail.php',
                data: $('#form_mail').serialize(),
                complete: function(html) {
                    console.log(html);
                    $('#message').show().text(html).fadeOut(3000, "linear");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Think you will need to post mail.php code too

Comment: console.log should tell you that `html` may be an object that have some properties

Comment: Can you copy the output that you see in the console?

Comment: I recommend you to debug your script in Chrome and take a look at the html variable.

Comment: the mail.php code is:

  $to = "my.email@mail.com";
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_POST['oggetto'] ;
  $message = stripslashes($_POST['msg']) ;
  $headers = "From:" . $email;
  
  $reply = "Messaggio Inviato";
    
  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

  echo $reply;

Comment: have you tried `html.toString()`? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that, you used `complete` method instead of `success`. And the reason you get an object there, is pretty obvious. [From documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> complete: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus ) A function
>   to be called when the request finishes (after success and error
>   callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The
>   jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string
>   categorizing the status of the reques

See there? Good.

So to make it work as you expect, replace `complete` with `success`

```
 success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);
            $('#message').show().text(html).fadeOut(3000, "linear");
 }
```

Comment: It works! thanks a lot!!! I have learnt a lot! :)

I am newbie and I am a newbie here too (stackoverflow) I need a guide to understand everything about the site.. it is a little bit different from the forums :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding property "dataType"="html" or "dataType"="text" to ajax options.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mail.php',
                data: $('#form_mail').serialize(),
                dataType: "html",
                complete: function(html) {
                    console.log(html);
                    $('#message').show().text(html).fadeOut(3000, "linear");
                }
            });
```

Comment: When you return the data, it does not know how to parse it, so it is considered objects. If tells the response how to desirailize it. So if I hit a web response two get two "car" objects, it would return the same you are seeing. I would then have to parse it to tell it how to handle it.

Comment: Looks like JQuery parsed the response, whatever had come from server.

Comment: Being explicit is always a good thing, so adding dataType, while it wasn't the answer, it provided good practise.

Answer (score 0):

jquery return a xhr object, not plain text.

To access the text response you need to call the responseText. See below

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'mail.php',
  dataType: "text"
  data: $('#form_mail').serialize(),
  complete: function(res) {
    $('#message').show().text(res.responseText).fadeOut(3000, "linear");
  }
});
```

Comment: @p-davide I guess you missed the responseText property

Comment: Yes, you're right, but `complete` with `beforeSend` are meant for things like showing/hiding a div with *please wait*-like messages, when ajax request is invoked. That's a bit abusive. `success` should be used instead

Comment: @bad_boy agreed. Just saw your answer. It make more sense to the question in place.

Answer (score -1):

I'd rather use done here as success is replaced by done in jQuery 1.8. Done handles both when it fails and when it succeeds, so you're able to handle both those cases in the done, rather than just having success. As bad_boy points out, from documentation:

> complete: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus ) A function
>   to be called when the request finishes (after success and error
>   callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The
>   jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string
>   categorizing the status of the reques

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_mail").validate({
        rules: {
            'email': {
                required: true,
            },
            'oggetto': {
                required: true,
            },
            'msg': {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mail.php',
                data: $('#form_mail').serialize()
            }).done(function(data){
                 $('#message').show().text(data).fadeOut(3000, "linear");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, you could also provide at least one sentence  which explains his obvious mistake

Comment: Yes, of course I was going to, just posted a script first for him to test.